# Is There Any Way We Can Get Url Of PopUp Windows In Parent Window

Tags: javascript, html

I want to Get a url of popUp window And Show It in Parent window.

```
<a href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','MyWindow',width=600,height=300); return false;">Click Here</a>
```

I Want to show popurl i.e google.com  in parent window.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It looks like you're supplying the url for the popup already.  Why not just grab that before you launch the popup?

Comment: or just say "Click here to open google.com"...

Comment: If you want the site itself displayed on the main window, you can use ajax-request to get the html, and dynamicly update your code, or consider iframe (know that this makes your site less secure)

Comment: Maybe think about using an iframe? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 1):

If the popup is from a third party domain (such as google.com), then you can't access the location.href property of the popup because of the "same origin policy".

If it's in the same domain, then you can get the URL by doing this on the parent window:

```
popUpWindow.location.href
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function onclick and have the url there as a variable:

```
<a href="#" onclick="my_function()">Click Here</a>
```

And then you can do anything you want with the url:

```
function my_function()
{
    var url = 'http://www.google.com';
    window.open(url ,'MyWindow',width=600,height=300);
    //show the url in an element
    return false;
}
```